# Sorting a list of custom data types by certain attribute in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell

Let's say we have a custom data type:

```
data Person = Person {  first_name :: String,
        last_name :: String,
        age :: Int
        } deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)
```

Let's also say I have a list of these Person data types. I've already made a function that sorts these Persons in order, but this is limited to the first value of each person, first_name. What I'm trying to do is modify the Person data type so that this sort function sorts by the age instead of first_name (besides just swapping the value order so that age is first).
I know I need to use the *instance* keyword to write my own *compare* function for Ord. This is where I'm stuck. Can anyone help me out?

Edit: Yep, this is HW-- I unfortunately need to do it the way I'm describing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest and most flexible way to deal with that problem, given that there are multiple valid ways to sort `Person` values, is not by changing the `Ord` instance, but by using a custom sorting function.

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

sortByAge :: [Person] -> [Person]
sortByAge = sortBy (comparing age)
```

`sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]` makes a custom sorting function from a comparison function, while `comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering` makes such a comparison function given, for instance, a field acessor. Be sure to have a good look at the involved type signatures in order to grok how everything fits together.

If you do need to change the `Ord` instance, here is how it would go. The syntax is as follows:

```
instance Ord Person where
    compare = undefined -- placeholder
```

[The documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord) tells us that, from all of the `Ord` methods, we just need to implement `compare`. Now, what should we replace `undefined` with? We want the comparison to be based on `age`, which is an `Int` field. Since `Int` is an instance of `Ord`, the answer is immediate:

```
instance Ord Person where
    compare x y = compare (age x) (age y)
```

Incidentally, the [definition of `comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-Ord.html#comparing) is:

```
comparing :: (Ord a) => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
comparing p x y = compare (p x) (p y)
```

And so we could write the instance in the style we used for the first solution:

```
instance Ord Person where
    compare = comparing age
```

Comment: I know this is definitely a better way, however this is a homework assignment and I must unfortunately complete it the way I described.

Comment: You're the man-- basically I didn't realize that (age x) is the way to "extract" the age from a Person =]

Comment: @Haskell Using record syntax gives you, for each field, a label, which can be used for setting the value and pattern matching, and a corresponding accessor function, which in your case is `age :: Person -> Int`.

Comment: I don't know if this a new addition to `Data.List`, but `sortOn` seems to work too - in this case you can write `sortByAge = sortOn age`.

Comment: @davidA Yup, `sortOn` was added to `Data.List` after I posted this answer. Note that it differs from `sortBy . comparing` in that it keeps the results of the projection function to avoid recomputation. That tends to be advantageous performance-wise if the projection function is somewhat expensive, which is not the case of something as cheap as `age`. (See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417687/how-to-change-ord-instance-for-tuple-of-type-string-int-without-declaring-a-n/57417801#comment101407041_57417801) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725970).)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Ord` from the list of derived type classes, if you have to write your own instance, the compiler generated one will clash. Also, this is not idiomatic, and I don't recommend this in general.

You can write the Ord instance yourself now the usual way:

```
instance Ord Person where
    compare b1 b2 = ...
```

I'll let you fill in the details as a useful exercise. Once that's done, the normal sort function will do what you want.

Comment: thanks for your response. This is where I've been at for last few hours. I don't know how to "connect" b1 and b2 to age of Persons

Comment: @Haskell `b1` and `b2` are persons (you can confirm that by considering the type of `compare`); you need to get hold of their ages and compare them. (With these hints, you might want to try it again now before reading the spoilers in my edited answer...)

Comment: @Haskell: One further hint -- ages are Ints and Ints are an instance of Ord.

Answer (score 0):

to the addition to above answer adding one more properties to it, that is if a custom data type have any repetition based on some value in that , we can add nub command to remove that. here is the code its working.

```
import Data.List(sortBy,nub)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
data User = User {
    userName::String,
    userId::Int
    } deriving (Show)
instance Eq User where
    (==) u1 u2 = userId u1 Prelude.== userId u2

task1 :: [User] -> [User]
task1 =(sortBy (comparing userId)).nub
```

the function that can sort in the order of userId as well as remove duplicates from a list of User types [User]
userId is a unique property and two user types with the same value for userId are considered duplicates.
The function signature is:
task1 :: [User] -> [User]