# Is there such a thing as maximumWith?

Tags: sorting, haskell, foldable

Specifically I'm searching for a function 'maximumWith',

```
maximumWith :: (Foldable f, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> a
```

Which behaves in the following way:

```
maximumWith length [[1, 2], [0, 1, 3]] == [0, 1, 3]
maximumWith null [[(+), (*)], []] == []
maximumWith (const True) x == head x
```

My use case is picking the longest word in a list.
For this I'd like something akin to `maximumWith length`.

I'd thought such a thing existed, since `sortWith` etc. exist.

Comment: Isn't that just `maximumBy . comparing`?

Comment: @melpomene: yes, although it might be better to first "map" to 2-tuples with the element and its comparator value, to avoid recalculating `f xi` each time.

Comment: The function doesn't seem to exist, but its name should be `maximumOn` (by analogy with the now quite popular [`sortOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn)). I don't think `sortWith` is seriously used, that seems to be more of a forgotten experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me collect all the notes in the comments together...

Let's look at `sort`. There are 4 functions in the family:

- [`sortBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sortBy) is the actual implementation.
- `sort = sortBy compare` uses `Ord` overloading.
- `sortWith = sortBy . comparing` is the analogue of your desired `maximumWith`. However, this function has an issue. The ranking of an element is given by applying the given mapping function to it. However, the ranking is not memoized, so if an element needs to compared multiple times, the ranking will be recomputed. You can only use it guilt-free if the ranking function is very cheap. Such functions include selectors (e.g. `fst`), and `newtype` constructors. YMMV on simple arithmetic and data constructors. Between this inefficiency, the simplicity of the definition, and its location in `GHC.Exts`, it's easy to deduce that it's not used that often.
- [`sortOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sortOn) fixes the inefficiency by decorating each element with its image under the ranking function in a pair, sorting by the ranks, and then erasing them.

The first two have analogues in `maximum`: `maximumBy` and `maximum`. `sortWith` has no analogy; you may as well write out `maximumBy (comparing _)` every time. There is also no `maximumOn`, even though such a thing would be more efficient. The easiest way to define a `maximumOn` is probably just to copy `sortOn`:

```
maximumOn :: (Functor f, Foldable f, Ord r) => (a -> r) -> f a -> a
maximumOn rank = snd . maximumBy (comparing fst) . fmap annotate
  where annotate e = let r = rank e in r `seq` (r, e)
```

There's a bit of interesting code in `maximumBy` that keeps this from optimizing properly on lists. It also works to use

```
maximumOn :: (Foldable f, Ord r) => (a -> r) -> f a -> a
maximumOn rank = snd . fromJust . foldl' max' Nothing
    where max' Nothing x = let r = rank x in r `seq` Just (r, x)
          max' old@(Just (ro, xo)) xn = let rn = rank xn
                                         in case ro `compare` rn of
                                                 LT -> Just (rn, xo)
                                                 _ -> old
```

These pragmas may be useful:

```
{-# SPECIALIZE maximumOn :: Ord r => (a -> r) -> [a] -> a #-}
{-# SPECIALIZE maximumOn :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> a #-}
```

Comment: Your implementation of `maximumOn` does not optimize well, even when fully specialized. I don't really know why that is. But there's a version that uses `foldl'` (or `foldr`) to maintain explicit state, doesn't impose a  `Functor` constraint, and (therefore) doesn't build an intermediate list.

Comment: @dfeuer Really? It seems to [come out fine](https://www.godbolt.org/z/LzoXiw), just a bit weird.

Comment: That doesn't even appear to be optimized (and I don't know how to use that tool). When I looked at the Core from `-O2`, I saw that `map` had survived.

Comment: When I look at the Core under `-O2`, I see an unoptimized definition of `maximumOn`, followed by an unholy spray of things like `main_$s$wgo1` that represent the single, somewhat optimized call to it in `main`.

Comment: Try writing a module that only exports `maximumOn`. That should get you much more meaningful Core.

Comment: @dfeuer I did that and I got the exact same thing. I put `maximumOn` in `module T where maximumOn = _`, put `main` on its own in `module Main where import T; main = _`. The Core shows that `maximumOn`, in its own module, is entirely unoptimized. It also shows me that that doesn't matter, because in `Main`, there is no call to `maximumOn` anyway, as it gets inlined and replaced with a loop.

Comment: Oh, I see, you haven't specialized any. Try `maximumOn_spec :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> a; maximumOn_spec f xs = maximumOn f xs`. It doesn't look so great. I think the fact that your executable example uses a literal list may be confusing matters somewhat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181578/discussion-between-htnw-and-dfeuer).

Answer (score 2):

HTNW has explained how to do what you asked, but I figured I should mention that for the specific application you mentioned, there's a way that's more efficient in certain cases (assuming the words are represented by `String`s). Suppose you want

```
longest :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

If you ask for `maximumOn length [replicate (10^9) (), []]`, then you'll end up calculating the length of a very long list unnecessarily. There are several ways to work around this problem, but here's how I'd do it:

```
data MS a = MS
  { _longest :: [a]
  , _longest_suffix :: [a]
  , _longest_bound :: !Int }
```

We will ensure that `longest` is the first of the longest strings seen thus far, and that `longest_bound + length longest_suffix = length longest`.

```
step :: MS a -> [a] -> MS a
step (MS longest longest_suffix longest_bound) xs =
    go longest_bound longest_suffix xs'
  where
    -- the new list is not longer
    go n suffo [] = MS longest suffo n
    -- the new list is longer
    go n [] suffn = MS xs suffn n
    -- don't know yet
    go !n (_ : suffo) (_ : suffn) =
      go (n + 1) suffo suffn

    xs' = drop longest_bound xs

longest :: [[a]] -> [a]
longest = _longest . foldl' step (MS [] [] 0)
```

Now if the second to longest list has `q` elements, we'll walk at most `q` conses into each list. This is the best possible complexity. Of course, it's only significantly better than the `maximumOn` solution when the longest list is much longer than the second to longest.

Comment: Your version is, in my testing, slightly less efficient than this: https://gist.github.com/hr-schueler/fd00ccc06e56f3298b45e37c714f208f

Comment: @MarkNeu, that's quite surprising to me, since that version walks each list twice. Did you compile with optimization? Mine will surely be bad if the `MS` values aren't unboxed.

Comment: Also, what GHC version did you use?

Comment: I used GHC 8.2.2

Comment: @MarkNeu, could you reveal your tests? And what optimization level did you use?

Comment: It wasn't a sophisticated test, I just played around a bit. Disregard my information, there is no professional basis for it.

Comment: @MarkNeu, it's not about being professional; I'm just curious.

Comment: I just used `:set +s` in GHCi

Comment: @MarkNeu, that explains it. Unless you use `-fobject-code` and either `-O` or `-O2`, code loaded in GHCi isn't optimized. Unoptimized, my code is quite bad, because each step allocates a new `Int` and a new `MS` value. But optimized, GHC will unbox the `Int`s into `Int#`s (kind of like switching from `Integer` objects in Java to `int` values). And then it uses something called a worker-wrapper transformation to eliminate the `MS` values. The whole thing becomes a non-allocating loop, which should be very fast. Your version is a bit better unoptimized, but optimization won't improve it much.